# Image within anchor tag makes unwanted horizontal space also clickable link

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to center-align an image in a page while also turning the image into a clickable link. Here is my attempt:

```css
a {
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
}

img {
  background: lightgreen;
  border: thin solid green;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="kitten"></a>
```

While the image has become a link, the problem is that most of the horizontal space on both sides of the image has also become clickable link. Why does it happen? Is there anyway to prevent that, so that only the image is a clickable link?

Comment: Why don't use inline-block to img css?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Can you elaborate how to solve the problem with `display: inline-block`? The reason we have `display: block` in the code above is so that we can center it with `margin: 0 auto`. That benefit will be lost if we use `display: inline-block`. Here is the result I get: https://jsbin.com/suyoneboro/edit?html,css,output The image is no longer at the center. Do you know how to make this work with `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Have you try my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of using a div to centre the image link.

```css
a {
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
}

img {
  background: lightgreen;
  border: thin solid green;
  width: 25%;     
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="kitten"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How suggest #yinsweet use container, i use other method with just text align on container like that:

```css
a {
  background: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
}

img {
  background: lightgreen;
  border: thin solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container{
  
  text-align:center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="kitten"></a>
</div>
```